# Выделить словосочетание из строки

Tags: c#

Есть строка "Count  ComponentName                  RefDes                         PatternName                    Value                          ТУ                             Дата создания                  Дата изменения                 Производитель"

Есть необходимость разбить ее в массив строк, так что бы каждый элемент был отдельно, что-то вроде:

```
1.Count
2.ComponentName
.
.
. 
7.Дата создания
8.Дата изменения
9.Производитель.
```

Если бы не пункты 7 и 8, вопроса бы не возникло, ибо можно было бы просто сделать `.Split(' ')`. Но сплит делит пункты 7 и 8, что делать не надо.

Наверное, как-то можно это сделать через регулярные выражения, но пока совсем не получается. Подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Исходную строку менять нельзя так? Ведь по сути ComponentName мог бы тоже быть разделен пробелом.

Comment: ComponentName, RefDes, PatternName пробелами не разделяются. Они всегда без пробела. А вот 7 и 8 пункт всегда с пробелом. С самой строкой ничего делать не выйдет, она формируется другой программой. То есть по факту я могу оперировать той строкой, что пришла.

Comment: Как вариант - проверять пункты на букву в верхнем регистре. Сделать такую проверку достаточно просто используя linq. Просто проверяем каждую букву на "isUpper" и потом формируем блок. Можно и от обратного - после выполнения Split проверить все блоки на заглавные буквы - если нет в начале заглавной, то удалить текущий блок, а содержимое прицепить к n-1 блоку.

Comment: А какое конкретно условие деления? Почему «Дата» и «изменения» вместе, а «ТУ» и «Дата» раздельно? Сформулируйте правило, без него вопрос не имеет смысла.

Comment: Ну и если входная строка фиксирована, просто возьмите готовое разбиение и не морочьте себе голову.

Comment: "Сделать такую проверку достаточно просто используя linq" Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это будет выглядеть?

Answer (score 3):

Из описания не совсем ясно, каков принцип разделения.

Предположим, что разделять нужно по словам, начинающимся с заглавной буквы. Тогда можно использовать регулярное выражение, с ним код получается очень кратким.

```
string input = "Count ComponentName RefDes PatternName Value ТУ Дата создания Дата изменения Производитель";

string pattern = @" (?=\p{Lu})";
var result = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

`Lu` - это [категория](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_11) Юникода *прописные буквы*.

---

Если принцип разделения строго основан на позициях (индексах) элементов, то используем простой топорный код:

```
var result = input.Split().ToList();
result[6] += " " + result[7];
result[8] += " " + result[9];
result.RemoveAt(9);
result.RemoveAt(7);
```

После расщепления строки по пробелам, конкатенируем нужные слова, после чего удаляем лишние.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string[] doSome (long n)
    {
        // your code
    var string1 = "Count ComponentName RefDes PatternName Value ТУ Дата создания Дата изменения Производитель";
    var res = string1.Split(' '); // Простой сплит для решения влоб
    var length = res.Length;
    var result = new String[length];
    var tmpStr = ""; 
    var counter = 0;
    //далее мы проверяем каждое слово на заглавную букву - проход идет от конца
    for (int i=length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        var substring = res[i];
        if (substring[0].ToString() != substring[0].ToString().ToUpper()){
             Console.WriteLine("NOT GOOD");
             if (tmpStr !=String.Empty) tmpStr += " "; // добавим пробелы если название состоит из 3+ слов.
             tmpStr += substring;
        }
        else
        {
            // Заглавная буква - проверяем нашли ли мы что-то раньше
            if (tmpStr!=String.Empty)
            {
                // если да - то мы добавляем в текущий элемент то, что мы нашли
                result[counter] = substring +" "+ tmpStr;
                tmpStr = "";
            }
            else
            {
                  // иначе просто добавляемв готовый результат
                 result[counter] = substring;
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
       Array.Reverse(result);// инвернтируем т.к. проходили массив с конца.
       Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
       foreach (var sub in result)
           Console.WriteLine(sub); 
       return result;
    }
```

Я набросал тут решение на скорую руку, но оно не оптимизировано ну никак =). Просто чтобы была идея. А вот с linq я к сожалению не силен - надо подумать.